# pillow/PIL doesn't accurately identify the creation time of an image via getexif()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, exif

I am writing a small python script to organize my photo collection basing on the years they were taken.

I used Python's pillow library parsing the images to extract `DateTime`. For most pictures it seemed working. I did notice, however there were two photos identified as being taken in 1980, which was simply wrong. I checked the tags of these two images, they were far fewer than normal - only four of them:

```
ExifVersion              : 0230
ComponentsConfiguration  : 
FileSource               : 
FlashPixVersion          : 0100
```

Normally the tag numbers should be dozens, as shown in this the article [How to Extract Image Metadata in Python](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extracting-image-metadata-in-python), and when I picked the particular tag for `DateTime`, it did return a date string with year 1980:

```
Image.open(img_path).getexif()[36867]
```

This returned `1980:01:01 00:08:29`, which is absurd in the sense that 1980 was like stone age, digital camera was way futuristic. `:-)`.

Needless to say this is troublesome in that, while the year of 1980 can be singled out right away as impossible, what if the library wrongly identifies the creation date but still the date looks plausible?

I used Python 3.x in Linux. Pillow lib version: 7.0.0

Comment: Try running `exiftool` on your unhappy images. It is normally the reference for EXIF data.

Comment: 01-Jan-1980 sure looks like the start of an epoch—the origin of some sort of time measurement system, see [Notable epoch dates in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing)—so it may be some sort of default if the data isn't present or is malformed. Since pillow is open source, I suggest you look at the source code and see what's going on.

Comment: Theres nothing that forces an image to have tags/metadata so maybe you can establish if the exif data or datetime is present before assuming the date is valid?